# Upgrading SDK for Flex Builder 3

Tags: apache-flex, sdk

I've got Flex Builder 3 running on a Mac. I'm using the Flex 3.2 SDK. I'd like to upgrade the SDK, so that I can target Flash Player 10. I've never upgraded the SDK; and I don't want to blow it and foul up my old projects.

I found this [link](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+3) to upgrade the SDK, but I'm not sure which version to upgrade to-- milestone, stable, or nightly. Also, which type-- Adobe Flex SDK, Open Source Flex SDK, or Adobe Add-ons. I would assume that I need the Adobe Flex SDK.

I also found this upgrade [link](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/entitlement/index.cfm?e=flex3sdk). Should I use this version instead?

I want to keep using Flex Builder 3. I'm not ready to upgrade to Flash Builder 4, yet.

As I understand it, I download the SDK, uninstall Flash, got to Preferences->Flex->Installed SDKs and add the zip, and then re-install Flash. If I want to work on an old project, I just select the old SDK.

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Adobe Flex SDK is the one you want, a stable release. Your understanding of the installation is correct except you don't need to uninstall and reinstall Flash unless you're switching flash player versions, and unless I'm mistaken you can't select the zip without extracting it to a directory first.